# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError gherkin/ParserException - Can't run cucumber test

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

[image]

``

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>############<</groupId>
  <artifactId>############</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.16-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>############</name>

  <properties>
    <!--Plugin Config-->
    <allure.html.report.output>${project.basedir}/target/results/allure-html</allure.html.report.output>
    <allure.json.results.output>${project.basedir}/allure-results</allure.json.results.output>

    <slf4j.version>2.0.3</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.4.4</logback.version>
    <selenium.version>4.5.3</selenium.version>
    <testng.version>7.5</testng.version>
    <assertj.version>3.23.1</assertj.version>
    <wdm.version>5.1.0</wdm.version>
    <awaitility.version>4.2.0</awaitility.version>
    <browsermob.version>2.1.5</browsermob.version>
    <zapclient.version>1.10.0</zapclient.version>
    <axel.version>4.4.2</axel.version>
    <javafaker.version>1.0.2</javafaker.version>
    <extentreports.version>5.0.9</extentreports.version>
    <allure.version>2.19.0</allure.version>
    <allure-maven.version>2.11.2</allure-maven.version>
    <cucumber.version>7.9.0</cucumber.version>
    <java-client.version>8.2.0</java-client.version>
    <rest-assured.version>5.2.0</rest-assured.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
    <selenium-support.version>4.5.3</selenium-support.version>
    <webdrivermanager.version>5.3.0</webdrivermanager.version>
    <selenium-chrome-driver.version>4.5.3</selenium-chrome-driver.version>
    <maven-clean-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-clean-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-cucumber-reporting.version>7.9.0</maven-cucumber-reporting.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.2.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <maven-install-plugin.version>2.5.2</maven-install-plugin.version>
    <maven-deploy-plugin.version>2.8.2</maven-deploy-plugin.version>
    <maven-site-plugin.version>3.12.0</maven-site-plugin.version>
    <maven-project-info-reports-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-project-info-reports-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <spotless-maven-plugin.version>2.22.8</spotless-maven-plugin.version>
    <browserstack-local-java.version>1.0.6</browserstack-local-java.version>
    <project.encondig>UTF-8</project.encondig>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>${project.encondig}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.encondig}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <commons-codec.version>1.15</commons-codec.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.7</aspectj.version>
  </properties>


  <profiles>
  <!-- Vendor profiles-->
  <profile>
    <id>browserstack</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
              <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testrunner/AdminTestng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
            <systemProperties>
              <property>
                <name>cucumber.plugin</name>
                <value>json:target/cucumber.json,io.qameta.allure.cucumber5jvm.AllureCucumber5Jvm</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                <name>cucumber.filter.tags</name>
                <value>@test</value>
              </property>
            </systemProperties>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
  </profiles>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <version>${assertj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-grid</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
      <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
      <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
      <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
      <version>${browsermob.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.zaproxy</groupId>
      <artifactId>zap-clientapi</artifactId>
      <version>${zapclient.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.deque.html.axe-core</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
      <version>${axel.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
      <version>${javafaker.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
      <version>${extentreports.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
      <version>${java-client.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium-support.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
      <artifactId>browserstack-local-java</artifactId>
      <version>${browserstack-local-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
     <version>${selenium-chrome-driver.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!--  jackson-databind: Work around for security vulnerability on io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager@5.2.0 (current latest)  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/datatable -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
      <version>7.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-cucumber5-jvm</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-clean-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <release>${java.version}</release>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
          </plugin>
        <!-- Source code linting using Spotless -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
          <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${spotless-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <java>
              <removeUnusedImports/>
              <googleJavaFormat>
                <style>GOOGLE</style>
                <reflowLongStrings>true</reflowLongStrings> <!-- optional (requires at least 1.8) -->
                <!-- optional: custom group artifact (you probably don't need this) -->
                <groupArtifact>com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format</groupArtifact>
              </googleJavaFormat>
            </java>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>test</id>
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
                <forkCount>4</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Duser.language=en</argLine>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                      -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                      -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber5jvm.AllureCucumber5Jvm"
                    </argLine>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>cucumberJsonParser</id>
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
              <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
              <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.test.automation.cucumber.allure.Beautify</mainClass>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
          <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
          <version>2.10.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <reportVersion>2.10.0</reportVersion>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-cucumber-reporting.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>execution</id>
              <phase>verify</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
                <projectName>cucumbertests</projectName>
                <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                <outputDirectory>target/report</outputDirectory>
                <jsonFiles>
                  <param>cucumber.json</param>
                </jsonFiles>
                <!--enableFlashCharts>false</enableFlashCharts-->
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

``

I am running my cucumber selenium project with `mvn clean test -P <profile_name>`

When I run the test I get the below error:
`[ERROR]   TestRunner>AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.setUpClass:27 ? Cucumber java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/ParserException`
I have attached my dependency tree pic and also attached the gherkin/parserexception class in my libraries [image]

I am running my cucumber selenium project with `mvn clean test -P <profile_name>`

When I run the test I get the below error:
`[ERROR]   TestRunner>AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.setUpClass:27 ? Cucumber java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/ParserException`
I have attached my dependency tree pic and also attached the gherkin/parserexception class in my libraries

Comment: Sorry my cucumber version used is 7.9.0 , java used is 17

Comment: Did you see the dependency on `allure-cucumber5-jvm`?

Comment: yes, i excluded gherkin form it so it wont clash with gherkin coming from cucumber-core

Comment: Why is it for cucumber 5?

Comment: Sorry guys please be specific with your questions so I can answer better

Comment: There is only one person you are talking too.

Comment: Sorry yes . can you please tell me what other details you need from me for helping

Comment: Why are you using `allure-cucumber5-jvm` with cucumber 7?

Comment: I tried with cucumber 5.7.0 and then started using 7 as I am getting the same error

Comment: Do you understand that the version of Cucumber and Allure are connected? And you may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example because if changing the obviously wrong thing doesn't solve the problem your problem is too big.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks os much for your time in reaidng my question and trying to attempt Mr. M.P. Korstanje
I managed to come over the problem. I have changed the cucumber versin to 7 and allurecucumberjvm version to 7 as well and luckily dont get the error any more. Though I get a stepdef error message as below which i will try to solve.

```
threw exception with message: Input must be set
```

Thanks again for your time